# Project Hamster notifications missing on upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, notification, hamster

I have upgraded from an almost default 11.10 install to 12.04. All went well and I can login, logout, etc. without any problem.

One very interesting thing about the Project Hamster notifications, though. I have set Hamster to remind after every 27 mins. I do not get these notifications. However, if there is no activity set, I see the notification.

In 11.10, I used to get both the notifications.

What is wrong? How do I set it right?

By the way, the notifications work quite well in Unity. But in Gnome, the problem continues.

Comment: Bump! Am I asking it on the wrong forum?

Comment: To get an answer as to whether or not AU is the right place to ask something, I recommend posting a question about that on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the notifications are now back in git master. 
[Follow the instructions here](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster#readme) for how to install (it's pretty straight forward).

Also when looking for hamster answers i can recommend always checking with the buglist ;)
https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/issues?sort=created&state=open